# How to avoid multiple results from sub query

Tags: mysql

Hi guys i am new bie to MySQL,this might be

easier to question but i am totally new for mysql.

i have two tables order and shops the Desc of two 
tables look like this....

OrdersTable.

```
order id: 
ordername:
shopnum(fk)
```

Shopstable*

```
shopname:
shopnum(pk):
```

i am using sub query like this,to get the shops name which have most number of orders....
like...19 xyzshop
.        13 hjjddshop
.         6 reebok shop

```
select shopname 
from shopstable 
where shopnum in
    (select count(orderid) as highest ,shopnum 
     from orderTable 
     group by shopnum)
```

it throws error,display column should be 1,its because the subquery is returning 2 results...so how do i avoid that and get the appropriate result...help will be appreciated...:):)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not complaining because the subquery returns 2 results but two columns. But even if it did only return a single column, it would return 2 results and the main query would do the same.

No need for a subquery in any case:

```
SELECT s.shopname 
FROM Shopstable s 
JOIN OrdersTable o ON s.shopnum=o.shopnum 
GROUP BY s.shopname 
ORDER BY count(*) DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
select shopname 
from shopstable 
where shopnum in
    (select shopnum 
     from orderTable 
     group by shopnum
     order by count(*) DESC
     limit 1)
```

Comment: +1 . . . But you should change the `in` to `=`, in my opinion.

Comment: I thought about that, but decided to leave it as is. If the `orderTable` table is empty, the subquery returns zero rows, and `IN` is then more appropriate (I think strict SQL doesn't allow `=` when the subquery is null, although MySQL is tolerant of it by default).

Comment: . . In a context where a scalar subquery returns no rows, then the value is treated as empty.  I'm pretty sure this is ANSI standard behavior; it is how all databases I'm familiar with work.  As a result, any comparison other than `is null` will not evaluate to true.

Answer (score 0):

remove `count(orderid) as highest ,` in your query. you should only select one column in your subquery

Comment: Then how do i get shops name list which have highest num of orders

Answer (score 0):

i think you want something like this...

```
SELECT shopname, count(*) as highest 
FROM shopstable 
INNER JOIN orderTable ON (shopstable = orderTable.shopname)
GROUP BY shopstable.shopname
```

i think this is the result you want?