# Mysql: Query in Select

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables say `result ,person and person_detail`:

Result has 4 columns
`id, teacher (fk from person) , student(fk from person), percent`

Person has many columns
`id, address....etc.`

person_detail has 3 column
`id, name, person(fk for person)`

I want my result in something like :

`teacher.name, student.name, percent`

For this I tried out this query:

```
select 
(select pd.name from Person_detail pd where pd.person=r.teacher) as Madam,
(select pd.name from Person_detail pd where pd.person=r.student) as Student,
and r.percent from Result r;
```

But this is throwing me exception as sub query returns more then 1 row and on some of my friends query browser result is as message "ok".

Please can someone provide me solution for this?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Why not use JOIN rather than sub queries ?

Comment: No that is returning me result count then expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your subquery must return unique row , In your query either this `select pd.name from Person_detail pd where pd.person=r.teacher` or this `select pd.name from Person_detail pd where pd.person=r.student` returning multiple rows.

So if that result multiple rows you will get above error. If you want to get unique result then improve your where condition or use Top(1) to get unique row(Not recommended).

You can write above query without subquery like [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24442629/3583859)

Comment: Yes i ran those inner queries in isolation and found that result could have same teacher appearing many times. But that is the ideal case as same teacher could be present fro multiple student

Comment: Updated answer with link try it and let me know

Comment: Great that worked... So final solution was my same query I was using with just limiting the inner query result to 1....

Answer (score 2):

you need to use join, between result and two instances of person_details (one for student and one for teacher):

```
select pdt.name as madam, pds.name as student, r.percent from
result as r inner join person_detail as pdt on r.teacher = pdt.person 
inner join person_detail as pds on r.student = pds.person
```

Comment: this query does not worked because i think it is return me result for all combination as in result table i have just 160 result and the result returned by this is 1009